# Proof that, for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a \mathbb{Z} \subset b \mathbb{Z} \iff b \mid a$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation

I'm having some trouble proving this theorem. Here's what I have so far.

**Theorem.** For $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a \mathbb{Z} \subset b \mathbb{Z} \iff b \mid a$.

*Proof.* Fix two arbitrary integers, $a$ and $b$, and define the sets $a\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\mathbb{Z}$ containing all of their multiples.

Step 1: $a\mathbb{Z} \subset b \mathbb{Z} \implies b \mid a$.

First, suppose that $a \mathbb{Z} \subset b\mathbb{Z}$. Let $z$ be an arbitrary integer, so $y = a_iz_i \in a \mathbb{Z}$, which implies that $y = b_a z_a \in b \mathbb{Z}$, so w have $a_i z_i = b_a z_a$.

The reason for the subscripts is to hopefully come to some conclusion about the divisibility of $b$. Euclid's Lemma is the first fact that comes to mind, but clearly neither of these terms are prime. The argument, conceptually, is something to the effect of this: the term on the left clearly must divide either $b_a$ or $z_a$. If it divides $z_a$, we can continue to move factors toward the 'b' term so that we allow $z_i$ and $z_a$ to be relatively prime, which then requires that $a$ divide $b$ to maintain equality. I'm unsure on whether this is a satisfactory argument, and perhaps less sure on how to formalize it if it is.

Step 2: $b \mid a \implies a\mathbb{Z} \subset b\mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose $b \mid a$, so there exists some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $bc = a$. Let $az$ be an arbitrary element of $a\mathbb{Z}$. We have $az = (bc)z = b(cz)$, where $cz \in \mathbb{Z}$ by closure. Thus, $az \in b\mathbb{Z}$.

The second component of this seems far easier, assuming these are valid steps, but I still am struggling a bit with the first step. Any helpful comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the  1st way, don't make things more than they are: just note that $a\in a\mathbf Z$, hence $a\in b\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Thank you for this. Now that I think about this a bit more, this may be enough: that $a \in b\mathbb{Z}$, taking $a \cdot 1 \in a \mathbb{Z}$, means that $a = bz$ for some $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. So, $b \mid a$ by definition. Is this the correct line of reasoning?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct line of reasoning.

Comment: The reasoning of the second component is correct, just for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going a wrong path for step 1.

Suppose $a\mathbb{Z}\subset b\mathbb{Z}$; in particular $a\in b\mathbb{Z}$, so $a=bk$ for some integer $k$, which implies $b\mid a$.

Your step 2 is correct.